# Gzip encounters critical medium error on Linux only when called from C++

Tags: linux, gzip, ext4

I'm working on a program that extracts an archive with gzip as part of operation. I'm running it on linux, and each time my program calls gzip (using `system()` ), the system complains at me with an error:

```
 blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 205190608",
```

which ultimately causes gzip to suffer an input/output error.

However, fsck doesn't find any problem with /dev/sdb, and when I run the exact same command that my program calls via bash, no such error occurs. What is happening here?

Comment: That's not related to c or c++. Even doesn't look like a programming problem. Probably that better goes to [SE Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Maybe a weak sector on your disk that only triggers from a particular access sequence.  Try renaming the 'bad' file to another name, and make copy back to the original name to allocate different disk blocks to it.  ( I must say that the `blk_update_request` seems more like an output problem than an input one though)

Comment: It seems to be related to the details of the operation of system(), which does seem to be an effect of the implementation of C.

Comment: @infixed I'll try that.

Comment: @infixed no problems moving the file.

Comment: You could do a `fsck` and check for bad blocks.  Or try some smartdrive utility.  But this is probably the time to backup the important stuff and buy yourself a new harddrive